# Error while performing multiple linear regression using fitlm in matlab

Tags: matlab, linear-regression

I am trying to perform multiple linear regression using fitlm command. For that, I have the following vectors: 
FuelPrice ( 1*688 vector)
TotalFuelCap (1 * 688 vector)
Demand (1 * 688 vector)
These are the Independent variables
CO2EMis ( 1 * 688 vector) 
This is the dependent variable.

I have coded as below:

```
for i = 1: rScenarioCnt
    if rScenario{i}.status == 1
        Demand(i)= sum(rScenario{i}.YearAlloc.LoadAlloc);
        ECostMax(i) = rScenario{i}.ECostMax;
        CO2EmisMax(i) = rScenario{i}.CO2EmisMax;
        ECost(i) = rScenario{i}.YearAlloc.ECost;
        CO2Emis(i) =  rScenario{i}.YearAlloc.CO2Emis ;
        EmisCostYear(i) = rScenario{i}.YearAlloc.EmisCostYear ;
        CO2EmisYear(i) = sum(rScenario{i}.YearAlloc.CO2EmisYear);
        FuelCode(i) = rScenario{i}.randFuelCode ;
        TotFuelCapacity(i) = sum(rScenario{i}.Gen.byFuelCap{FuelCode(i)})
        FuelPrices(i) = rScenario{i}.Fuel.prices(FuelCode(i));
    else
        i
        disp('Not able to store in table');
    end

end

dsa = dataset(FuelPrices',TotFuelCapacity',Demand',CO2Emis','VarNames',{'FuelPrices','TotFuelCapacity','Demand','CO2Emis'});
T = eye(21);
X = CO2Emis;
mdl = fitlm(X,dsa,T);
```

I am getting the error below:

```
Not able to store in table
Error using classreg.regr.TermsRegression.createFormula (line 728)
The terms matrix must have one column for each predictor variable, and the last column for the response variable.
Error in LinearModel.createFormula (line 1376)
            formula = classreg.regr.TermsRegression.createFormula(supplied,modelDef, ...
Error in LinearModel.fit (line 1212)
            model.Formula = LinearModel.createFormula(supplied,modelDef,X, ...
Error in fitlm (line 117)
model = LinearModel.fit(X,varargin{:});
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: How do expect to map 688 demands with only 10 prices?

Comment: I have changed the code and edited the post. can you please help me